# Mule 3.8 application showing multiple NoSuchBeanDefinitionException during mule server starting

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster, mule-module-jpa

I Upgraded my project from Mule 2.2 to Mule 3.8,Project is working fine,But during starting of Mule Server i am getting "Several exceptions in logs when logging level is DEBUG".

[WrapperListener_start_runner] SpringRegistry - No bean named 'quartz:-948818277' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'quartz:-948818277' is defined

[DEBUG] 2017-04-21 06:25:18.994 [WrapperListener_start_runner] SpringRegistry - No bean named 'endpoint.quartz.contestentsPhotoDelivery.task' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'endpoint.quartz.contestentsPhotoDelivery.task' is defined

[DEBUG] 2017-04-21 06:25:19.024 [WrapperListener_start_runner] SpringRegistry - No bean named 'endpoint:24812436' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'endpoint:24812436' is defined

[DEBUG] 2017-04-21 06:25:19.376 [WrapperListener_start_runner] SpringRegistry - No bean named 'vm:3767' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'vm:3767' is defined

There are many more similar "No bean named" Exception, pls let me if you need more Info.Thanks!

Comment: Please provinde some explanation of your problem.

Comment: Please now check above exception and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

During startup mule is looking for default connectors and beans, clustered components, etc.  If they are not defined, it exceptions and knows that feature is not available or to use your values instead.  This is normally handled in the background and you do not see it.  You are getting these reports only because you steps Mule's log reporting up to DEBUG level which is giving you a view into some of the internal workings.  This is not a worry and one of the reasons you do not bump Mule up to debug level reporting unless you really need to see what is going on because something is failing.  One could argue that Mule should have put this normal execution level logging at TRACE level, but it is debatable.

Comment: i resolved only two exception by adding below bean in "minimal-mule-config.xml" file Exception:-

No bean named "_mulePollingController" NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named "_muleClusterConfiguration"

Added beans
    <spring:bean name="_mulePollingController" class="org.mule.transport.DefaultPollingController"/>
 <spring:bean name="_muleClusterConfiguration" class="org.mule.config.NullClusterConfiguration"/>
I know these exception not effect application but i have to submit application without any exception.If you have any more information please share.

Comment: You should ignore debug messages. Trying to ''fix' them this way could cause actual issues.